# Recycler view setLayoutManager Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

RecyclerView isn't showed without setLayoutManager, but setLayoutManager makes my program crash. This method was demonstrated in all of the tutorials I have watched. Yeah, I know, there is too much code with a lot of garbage, but the error can be anywhere, so I hope you can help me(

StoreInfoPage.java (get it just like the MainActivity)

```
public class StoreInfoPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.store_info_page);

        RecyclerView lastMonthSellsList = findViewById(R.id.last_month_sells_list);
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        products.add(new Product(4, 5, true, true, 16000, 12000));
        products.add(new Product(4, 5, true, true, 16000, 12000));

        StoreSellingAdapter adapter = new StoreSellingAdapter(this, products);
        lastMonthSellsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        lastMonthSellsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

store_info_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".StoreInfoPage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="Кофе 3в1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="Чёрное Кофе"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:showText="true"
        android:text="ДОЛГ"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
        android:text="Добавить"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
        android:text="ПРОШЛЫЙ МЕСЯЦ"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/last_month_sells_list"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

store_sell_list_table_row.xml (Adapter xml for RecyclerView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:id="@+id/sells_list_adapter_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/whiteCoffeeAdapter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="Кофе 3в1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/whiteCoffeeQuantityAdapter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/whiteCoffeePriceAdapter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/whiteCoffeeTotalPriceAdapter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blackCoffeeAdapter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="Чёрное Кофе"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blackCoffeeQuantityAdapter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blackCoffeePriceAdapter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blackCoffeeTotalPriceAdapter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView38"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView39"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/coffeeTotalPriceAdapter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text_view_adapter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ОПЛАЧЕНО"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

StoreSellingAdapter (Adapter class)

```
public class StoreSellingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreSellingAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Product> products;
    private Context context;

    StoreSellingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.store_sell_list_table_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = products.get(position);
        holder.whiteCoffeeQuantity.setText(product.getWhiteCoffeeQuantity());
        holder.blackCoffeeQuantity.setText(product.getBlackCoffeeQuantity());
        holder.whiteCoffeePrice.setText(product.getWhiteCoffeePrice());
        holder.blackCoffeePrice.setText(product.getBlackCoffeePrice());
        holder.whiteCoffeeTotalPrice.setText(product.getWhiteCoffeeTotalPrice());
        holder.blackCoffeeTotalPrice.setText(product.getBlackCoffeeTotalPrice());
        holder.coffeeTotalPrice.setText(product.getCoffeeTotalPrice());
        if(product.isDebt() && product.isPaid()) {
            holder.statusTextViewAdapter.setText("ДОЛГ(ОПЛАЧЕНО)");
            holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ef5350"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView whiteCoffeeQuantity;
        TextView blackCoffeeQuantity;
        TextView whiteCoffeePrice;
        TextView blackCoffeePrice;
        TextView whiteCoffeeTotalPrice;
        TextView blackCoffeeTotalPrice;
        TextView coffeeTotalPrice;
        TextView statusTextViewAdapter;
        LinearLayout parentLayout;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            whiteCoffeeQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.whiteCoffeeQuantityAdapter);
            blackCoffeeQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blackCoffeeQuantityAdapter);
            whiteCoffeePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.whiteCoffeePriceAdapter);
            blackCoffeePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blackCoffeePriceAdapter);
            whiteCoffeeTotalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.whiteCoffeeTotalPriceAdapter);
            blackCoffeeTotalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blackCoffeeTotalPriceAdapter);
            coffeeTotalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coffeeTotalPriceAdapter);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sells_list_adapter_layout);
            statusTextViewAdapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_text_view_adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
public class Product {
    private int whiteCoffeeQuantity;
    private int blackCoffeeQuantity;
    private boolean isDebt;
    private boolean isPaid;
    private int whiteCoffeePrice;
    private int blackCoffeePrice;
    private int whiteCoffeeTotalPrice;
    private int blackCoffeeTotalPrice;
    private int coffeeTotalPrice;

    public Product(int whiteCoffeeQuantity, int blackCoffeeQuantity, boolean isDebt, boolean isPaid, int whiteCoffeePrice, int blackCoffeePrice) {
        this.whiteCoffeeQuantity = whiteCoffeeQuantity;
        this.blackCoffeeQuantity = blackCoffeeQuantity;
        this.isDebt = isDebt;
        this.isPaid = isPaid;
        this.whiteCoffeePrice = whiteCoffeePrice;
        this.blackCoffeePrice = blackCoffeePrice;
        whiteCoffeeTotalPrice = whiteCoffeeQuantity*whiteCoffeePrice;
        blackCoffeeTotalPrice = blackCoffeeQuantity*blackCoffeePrice;
        coffeeTotalPrice = whiteCoffeeTotalPrice+blackCoffeeTotalPrice;
    }

    public int getWhiteCoffeeQuantity() {
        return whiteCoffeeQuantity;
    }

    public void setWhiteCoffeeQuantity(int whiteCoffeeQuantity) {
        this.whiteCoffeeQuantity = whiteCoffeeQuantity;
    }

    public int getBlackCoffeeQuantity() {
        return blackCoffeeQuantity;
    }

    public void setBlackCoffeeQuantity(int blackCoffeeQuantity) {
        this.blackCoffeeQuantity = blackCoffeeQuantity;
    }

    public boolean isDebt() {
        return isDebt;
    }

    public void setDebt(boolean debt) {
        isDebt = debt;
    }

    public boolean isPaid() {
        return isPaid;
    }

    public void setPaid(boolean paid) {
        isPaid = paid;
    }

    public int getWhiteCoffeePrice() {
        return whiteCoffeePrice;
    }

    public void setWhiteCoffeePrice(int whiteCoffeePrice) {
        this.whiteCoffeePrice = whiteCoffeePrice;
    }

    public int getBlackCoffeePrice() {
        return blackCoffeePrice;
    }

    public void setBlackCoffeePrice(int blackCoffeePrice) {
        this.blackCoffeePrice = blackCoffeePrice;
    }

    public int getWhiteCoffeeTotalPrice() {
        return whiteCoffeeTotalPrice;
    }

    public void setWhiteCoffeeTotalPrice(int whiteCoffeeTotalPrice) {
        this.whiteCoffeeTotalPrice = whiteCoffeeTotalPrice;
    }

    public int getBlackCoffeeTotalPrice() {
        return blackCoffeeTotalPrice;
    }

    public void setBlackCoffeeTotalPrice(int blackCoffeeTotalPrice) {
        this.blackCoffeeTotalPrice = blackCoffeeTotalPrice;
    }

    public int getCoffeeTotalPrice() {
        return coffeeTotalPrice;
    }

    public void setCoffeeTotalPrice(int coffeeTotalPrice) {
        this.coffeeTotalPrice = coffeeTotalPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your activity code ????

Comment: can you please provide the logcat?

Comment: How do we know the tutorial you're talking about. And how do we know what you've tried and the error you're getting.

Comment: please share your code?

Comment: Share your logcat or activity or fragment code.

Comment: I added more details, please check guys

Comment: What we need aren't more details know, but rather what is it that happens that makes you say "it doesn't work". Because we need to see what is it that doesn't work, and you're not showing us what that is. Show your error log. Tell us what you've debugged, and then, only then, someone may be able to help you. A recycler view *needs* a LayoutManager, so if it's crashing, it's likely you doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Oh guys, I'm so stupid. I just had a look at the logs and understood that everything was because of TextView.setText(Int); Yeah guys, just facepalm. I'm sorry I took your times, starting from now, I'm dummy.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know you!
Everything is because of TextView.setText(Int).
Just replace Int with String.valueOf(Int).